# #JavaScript If statement not working for setInterval

Tags: javascript, if-statement, setinterval

Here is my code

```
$('.match-dates').on('afterChange', function () {

        var currentSelectionDate =  $('.match-dates .slick-current > div > div').attr('data-date');
        var liveStatus;

        if(currentSelectionDate == null){
            liveStatus = 1;
            $.get('/api/index.php?request=GetLiveMatchesSpecial', function ( data ) {
                $('.lives').html(data);
            });

        } else {
            liveStatus = 0;
            $.get('/api/index.php?request=GetFixturesSpecial&date=' + currentSelectionDate, function ( data ) {
                $('.lives').html(data);
            });
        }

        if(liveStatus === 1){
            console.log(liveStatus);

            setInterval(function () {
                $.get('/api/index.php?request=GetLiveMatchesSpecial', function ( data ) {
                    $('.lives').html(data);
                });
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            console.log(liveStatus);

            clearInterval();

        }

    });
```

When var liveStatus = 0 it still loads setInterval function.
As you see I'm checking for values of var liveStatus and it works well.
Why i can't unload previously loaded setInterval function?

Thanks

Comment: You have to pass an argument to `clearInterval(…)`; look at its documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `clearInterval` to work, you have to pass it the result of the previous `setInterval` call that you want to clear. A `clearInterval()` with no parameters passed to it will do nothing. Eg:

```
let interval;
$('.match-dates').on('afterChange', function() {
  var currentSelectionDate = $('.match-dates .slick-current > div > div').attr('data-date');
  var liveStatus;
  if (currentSelectionDate == null) {
    liveStatus = 1;
    $.get('/api/index.php?request=GetLiveMatchesSpecial', function(data) {
      $('.lives').html(data);
    });
  } else {
    liveStatus = 0;
    $.get('/api/index.php?request=GetFixturesSpecial&date=' + currentSelectionDate, function(data) {
      $('.lives').html(data);
    });
  }
  if (liveStatus === 1) {
    console.log(liveStatus);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      $.get('/api/index.php?request=GetLiveMatchesSpecial', function(data) {
        $('.lives').html(data);
      });
    }, 5000);
  } else {
    console.log(liveStatus);
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
});
```

Comment: Using setInterval is not appropriate here.

You are doing clearInterval(interval) only when  `afterChange` event triggers again. But until then in background the `$get()` method will be called every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks you for reply. But wondering why setInterval still works when liveStatus is 0? I mean without clearInterval function why it loads again.

Comment: @VishnuKyatannawar How i can update data in every 5 second using other ways? Thanks

Comment: @user3446664 That's exactly what `interval`s do, they keep running after each timeout until cleared. If you only wanted to run the function once, you should use `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: @VishnuKyatannawar I need to break setInterval loop after that event :)

Comment: Does this event `$('.match-dates').on('afterChange'` both starts intervals  and also stops interval?

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval()` method repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

So every 5000ms the code written setInterval will be called.

So if `$('.match-dates').on('afterChange', function ()` event is triggered once with `liveStatus` as `0` that is enough, your `setInterval()` function will be called every 5 seconds now.

May be you should try using `setTimeout` instead.

The `setTimeout()` method sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once after the timer expires.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $.get('/api/index.php?request=GetLiveMatchesSpecial', function(data) 
  {
    $('.lives').html(data);
  });
}, 5000);
```